# Naming items based on their position in coordinates

Tags: terminology

I am making the base of an animation that will be used by third parties. It's a kind of radial animation with items around an object. Each "ray" should have a name so that its function is clear in the animation. And this is where I have the dilemma: I should find a simple and not extensive way to name each object. The sections are separated which can help with the names. As there are many elements that should be easily located, there are options that I rule out, such as naming them numerically.

If I start from the example of the image below, I have solved the blue items, but with the green and orange ones the problem begins:

- Item Medium Top Right Right?
- Item Small Top Right Top?
- Item North
- Item NWW

They are long and confusing solutions.

Regarding the grays, as they are sixteen, I think I will have no other option than to call them numerically.

Any ideas?

[image: Scheme]

I think this, although simple, no one will understand:

[image]

Comment: What will the user be doing with each individual dot, something like assigning a word/label to it?

Comment: Only locate the item for minimal changes

Answer (score 3):

You might consider entering a "location mode" that will show everything with a quick identifier. Since many people are familiar with section/location pairs being represented by a letter/number (think sports stadiums or theaters), it could assign sections with numbers, starting with 0 and radiating out by row. Letters would start with A in the topmost or top-rightmost position and run clockwise. (Letter O is omitted here to avoid confusion with the number zero.)

[image: Locator mode]

Comment: Good idea, I'm a bit stuck with the animation and lack the mental resources for this. I will see how it is implemented.

Comment: Great idea. You could also try to use the gray circle for the "letter-mapping". So that it defines the letters and outer circles use only these letters. E.g. in the upper image 3G would then be 3M. 5C would be 5K, 3F would be 3K. 2H --> 2Q, 4H --> 4Q, ...